# Capture all dropdown/select elements value with onclick and insert html total field

Tags: javascript

We are using a html quiz application that does not contain a total field for dropdowns/select elements. I would like to insert a html div total that captures ALL select elements with values while using click to capture changes. I've found pieces of my solution while searching but can't seem to put them all together. I don't have the ability to insert the eventlistener into the html directly.

What I have so far. Feel like im close but receiving x[i] not defined.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var i = 1;
sum = 0;
for (i; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    sum += Number(x[i].value);
});
}
```

All dropdowns are in the same repeated class:

```
<select class="qm_SELECT_sel"><option value=""></option>
```

Comment: add your html code too

Comment: *jquery*  $('.qm_SELECT_sel').change(function(){  $('.qm_SELECT_sel:selected').each(function(){ sum+=$(this).val();  });  $('.input_filed').val(sum); });

Comment: This worked. Script had to be at end of page. Guess its a pain trying with javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you getting x[i] as undefined because click even is bind with all of the select element but while firing click event in i it always passes the last valid of i
for example : if you have 3 dropdowns then it will click event with 3 of them but while clicking any dropdown it always passes 3.

to ignore this u had to kept that event bind to saperate function and pass element as a parameter to that function in this way value of each i is maintained

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var i = 1;
sum = 0;
for (i; i < x.length; i++) {
    bindSelectClick(x[i]);
}
function bindSelectClick(elem){
 elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    sum += Number(elem.value);
 });
}
```

Comment: This does not subtract values when/if they are changed.

Answer (score 1):

As per Your comment the finale answer is

```js
  

$('.qm_SELECT_sel').change(function(){
 
  var sum=0;
  
  $('.qm_SELECT_sel option:selected').each(function(){ 
    
    sum =Number(sum)+Number($(this).val());  
 
  }); 
  
     $('#total_filed').val(sum); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="1as"  class="qm_SELECT_sel">
      <option value=""  >select 1 </option>
       <option value="1" >1 </option>
       <option value="2" >2</option>
      </select>

    <select name="2asa" class="qm_SELECT_sel" >
      <option value="" >select 2 </option>
       <option value="1" >1 </option>
       <option value="2" >2</option>
      </select>

    <input name="input_field" id="total_filed" >
```